# Download entire directories from google cloud storage bucket using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud storage bucket, I can download objects using the `download_blob` function in python, I can also use the `gsutil cp` or `gcloud compute scp` function to download entire directories.

Is there a way to download an entire directory from the storage bucket using python as a single zip file.

doing it this way [Python - download entire directory from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748910/python-download-entire-directory-from-google-cloud-storage) requires me to download file by file.

Is there a way to download an entire directory at once ?

Comment: Any method you use, it will still be "file by file". Because one download request needs to be made per file. I think the linked answer will work for you just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storage has [no concept of "directories"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) -- instead, each blob can be given a name that can resemble a directory path. Downloading entire "directories" is the same as downloading all blobs with the same prefix.

This means that you can use wildcards with `gsutil`:

```
gsutil -m cp gs://bucket/data/abc/* .
```

would copy every blob whose name starts with `/data/abc/`.

Comment: If I do that, will the subdirectories go into subdirectories in my local computer?

Comment: Can this be done with python too ? Where directories go into directories, all the code I see only can’t do that

Comment: hey it doesn't work, it says no such directory, but when I do gsutil ls, I can see the directory